# Regex matching punctuation

Tags: java, regex

i would like to match a punctuation character specifically this `[` to a pattern and I don't know how. For example I have this string `P:[l,s]`, the first character `P` matches with this pattern `A-Z`, the second `:` matches with this `[:]`. what pattern matches with this `[`?

Comment: You also don't need to put the `:` into a character class, it has no special meaning and simply matches itself: use `:`.

Answer (score 5):

You want to escape it like this : `\[`. You should start reading simple regex tutorials such as [this one](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html).

Answer (score 0):

"[" is a special character and will need escaping. Try `\\[`